# How to extract database schema to xml content?

Tags: xml, database, schema

I need to extract the database schema to xml content.

Is there any open source tool or library which can perform schema extraction operation?

Is there any procedure available to generate the DB schema to xml content?

Example:

```
create table sample(id numeric(5) primary key)

<Tables>
  <Table Name="sample" Type="Table">
    <Column Name="id" DataType="numeric" IsNullable="NO" IsIdentity="0" Constraint="PRIMARY KEY" />
  </Table>
</Tables>
```

With below query mentioned in the answer same thing I need to 
implement for index, procedures....

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Or Is there any procedure available to generate the DB schema to xml content? @Erwin Smout

Comment: Yes there is.  Read the catalog, write an XML.

Comment: The point being : the criticism that applies to that particular [part of the] question is that it is "too broad".  You haven't even specified whether your database is managed by SQL or something else.  You also have not specified the XML structure you'd want (no .xsd, that is).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS '@Name', CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'Table' ELSE 'View' END AS '@Type',
(
    SELECT Column_Name as '@Name',
            DATA_TYPE as '@DataType',
            case data_type 
                when 'nvarchar' 
                then CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
                when 'varchar'  
                then CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
                else null 
            end  as '@Length',
            IS_NULLABLE AS '@IsNullable',
            COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') AS '@IsIdentity',

(SELECT tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE tc.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME AND cu.COLUMN_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.Column_Name) AS '@Constraint'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME
    order by INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For XML PATH ('Column'), type
)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC  
For XML PATH ('Table'),Root('Tables')
```

Comment: My doubt regarding generation of xml content based on the DB schema. Will it display the schema as xml content? And I'm getting error

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are getting? And yes this will generate XML content of the DB schema

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.                   This error I am getting

Comment: If a DB contains table alone it generates as xml

Comment: How the same way we will have with index and procedure also right?